# Unexpected T_VARIABLE, but it's not unexpected

Tags: php

I'm getting an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in  home2/chippery/public_html/login/text/loginStuff.php on line 4

Line 4:

> $pass = $_POST['password']

However, line 3 works fine:

> $user = $_POST['username']

Post is from:

```
<html>
<form action='loginStuff.php' method='POST'>
User: <input type='text' name='username'><br>
Pass: <input type='password' name='password'><br>
<input type='submit' value='Log In'>
</form>
</html>
```

I **just** got into PHP (less than an hour ago) so I'm sure it's a stupid mistake, but can you figure out what's wrong?

Comment: You may want to throw a `;` on the end of each of those lines.

Comment: Do they all have semicolons at the end? `$pass = $_POST['password'];` `$user = $_POST['username'];`?

Comment: you're missing a semicolon

Comment: It's better to paste your actual code to SO instead of excerpts -- this way you'll get better answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a semicolon at the end of each line.

Comment: +1, -- however only for statements. Not every line needs a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

End conditions/variable assignments/manupulations with a semicolon `;`

Example:

```
$Username = $_POST['Username']; // Solution
$Password = $_POST['Password']; // Solution
$Username = trim($_POST['Username']); // Example only
```

But not for if statements:

```
if (isset($_POST['Username'])){
   if (isset($_POST['Username'])){
     $Username = $_POST['Username'];
   }
} // No semi colon needed here, only inside the braces
```